# Why is my permission being denied to store FCM token data to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Error:

```
W/Firestore(24623): (21.6.0) [WriteStream]: (798288) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.
W/Firestore(24623): (21.6.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at devicetokens/cIvW6DrG5xnxJOhndbyq: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (24623): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

Flutter Code:

```
      _fcm.getToken().then((deviceToken){
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("devicetokens").add({
          'createdAt': DateTime.now(),
          'platform' : Platform.isIOS ? "iOS" : "Android",
          'token': deviceToken
        });
      });
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {   
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /devicetokens/{document=**} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write: if true; 
    }
  }
}
```

Using the above set of code, my objective is to retrieve the FCM token and store it in Firestore. I remember using this syntax previously and it worked then, but it seems that it hasn't been working as intended since the August update.

EDIT:- FWIW, I'm getting non-zero read counts in my usage tab, even though I haven't read from Firestore at all.

EDIT2:-  Tried the usual testing condition provided in the starting and it still failed.

EDIT3:- Posting the full error log, in case someone has any idea what's happening:

```
E/flutter ( 1788): #0      catchPlatformException (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:3)
E/flutter ( 1788): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 1788): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 1788): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:160:20)
E/flutter ( 1788): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
E/flutter ( 1788): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
E/flutter ( 1788): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
E/flutter ( 1788): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
E/flutter ( 1788): #8      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
E/flutter ( 1788): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1788): #9      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
E/flutter ( 1788): #10     MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:29:51)
E/flutter ( 1788): #11     DocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:82:22)
E/flutter ( 1788): #12     CollectionReference.add (package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:45:23)
E/flutter ( 1788): #13     _SlideDrawerState.startTime.<anonymous closure> (package:nawa/widgets/innerdrawer.dart:132:63)
E/flutter ( 1788): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 1788): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 1788): #16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
E/flutter ( 1788): #17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 1788): #18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
E/flutter ( 1788): #19     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
E/flutter ( 1788): #20     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
E/flutter ( 1788): #21     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
E/flutter ( 1788): #22     FirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart)
E/flutter ( 1788): #23     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 1788): #24     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 1788): #25     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
E/flutter ( 1788): #26     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 1788): #27     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
E/flutter ( 1788): #28     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
E/flutter ( 1788): #29     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
E/flutter ( 1788): #30     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
E/flutter ( 1788): #31     MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart)
E/flutter ( 1788): #32     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 1788): #33     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 1788): #34     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
E/flutter ( 1788): #35     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
E/flutter ( 1788): #36     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
E/flutter ( 1788): #37     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
E/flutter ( 1788): #38     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
E/flutter ( 1788): #39     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 1788): #40     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 1788): #41     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 1788): #42     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 1788): #43     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 1788): #44     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the August update"?

Comment: Wasn't there a large update around the mid of August for a whole host of Firebase products? Or was it just Firebase-Flutter integrations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your syntax is correct. Also if document-collection path doesn't have a rule set up for it and your db isn't in test mode (i.e you can read/write any path) the operation will fail with that `PERMISSION_DENIED` error

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /devicetokens/{deviceTokenId}  {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

Wildcards are represented with `{}` not `=**` like you have below

```
match /devicetokens/{document=**} {
  allow read: if false;
  allow write: if true; 
}
```

If all else fails, overwrite all your rules with the following snippet:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 10, 01); //Allow only until the 1st of October
    }
  }
}
```

It puts everything into test mode (read/write anywhere from anything). If your error still occurs then it's definitely a problem elsewhere

Comment: Can you please clarify where the syntax is incorrect? Is it in the flutter code or the rules?

Comment: @FarhanNawaz in your rules, my first code snippet is what it should be. The second is what you currently have.

Comment: I corrected it (Francesco previously suggested it too), but that didn't work either.

Comment: @FarhanNawaz Apologies, I forgot the write permission. Try it again with just `allow write;`

Comment: I tried with the testing conditions and it still failed :/.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {   
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /devicetokens/{deviceTokenId} {
        allow read: if false;
        allow write: if true; 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no other ideas.. Are you sure there is nothing mispelled and that Rules have been correctly deployed/activated?

Comment: Yep. Just a quick question, should I go through the whole process of initializing a Future wrapped around the mainApp?

Comment: I don't think so.